# Memcache cache result

Tags: php, performance, memcached

Consider the following code:

```
function getUser($uid) {
    global $_memcache;
    $u = $_memcache->get("user-".$uid);
    if( !$u) {
        $u = ... // get user from database
        $_memcache->set("user-".$uid,$u);
    }
    return $u;
}
```

Now, this function will probably be called a LOT. For instance, on the forum it may be called 30+ times in a single pageload. Is it worth doing the following, or is Memcache already optimal enough?

```
function getUser2($uid) {
    static $localcache = [];
    if( isset($localcache[$uid])) return $localcache[$uid];
    return $localcache[$uid] = getUser($uid);
}
```

Comment: Would you be calling the same function to get the same user id data 30+ times on a page or for 30 different users?

Comment: Well, that's not really predictable. For instance, if all 25 threads on a single page were made and last posted in by the same user, it'd be called 50 times with the same UID. Or if they were all made and posted in by different users, then it's 50 calls with different arguments.

Comment: Is your memcached instance on the same server as the executing code or remote?

Comment: It's on the same server as everything else.

Comment: @kolink, any comments on my suggestion below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ultimately memcached is in memory storage, just as storing the values in PHP array would be.  If the memcached instance is on the same server that you are running the code on, then I would definitely say just use memcached instead of both memcached and the PHP array, as you would end up just using ~ twice as much memory on the machine by storing the same data in memory twice.

If memcached is on seperate infrastructure (which is probably likely), then I guess I would consider what the size of the data stored for the user is going to be.  If it is large and you may store a large number of users in the PHP array, it means you could potentially be sucking up more memory on your web server than you find desirable, in which case accessing the data from memcached repeatedly, while being slightly slower for overall access time, would probably provide significant application performance under server load.

Personally, I would probably tend to lean towards relying on memcached for each request, as it is just more scalable.

Comment: @Mike,  you might want to comment on / give a rebuttal to my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Kolink, I want to put an alternative view to Mike.  First, if the number of getUser requests are of the order of ~50 / page or even a few hundred then the storage issue is immaterial.

Second the memcached runs out of process, so even if the memcached is on the same system, you are still getting hit with two usermode context switches per **get()** call, so the key issue here is a simple statistical one:  what is the expected number of user occurrences per page? If this is 2, say, then your local PHP cache will half the number of memcached-related context switches.

However, the real savings would be made by making use of the memcached *multi-get* functionality -- the PHP memcache extension uses this if you call **memcache::get()** with an array of values.  However, this requires a two-pass algorithm and some changes to the code.  One way to do this safely would be to use a locally cached getUser() as per your second example but add a 0th pass scan of the page structure to detect putative memcache get targets, do an unique sort and then prime the local cache with a multi-get based on this list.

The mainline could still use the cached get and fault back to the D/B to set the user-XXX in the memcache, but this way a high (say 95%) of user queries would be satisfied with a single out-of-process call to the memcached.

Yes, a bit of added complexity, but I think that the performance dividends make it well worthwhile trying.

Comment: Interesting point. This was my main concern, but after some testing it seems like everything works fine for now.